# Create two DB entries with relation in SqlAlchemy

Tags: python, database, sqlalchemy

I have to create two entries in a postgres database where the second entry would be child of the first one and marks this with a separate `parent` field that holds the `id` of the first entry.
Is there a better solution to achieve this than first create the parent, then query its `id` and fill it to the child?

My mapping:

```
class Report(Base):
    """
    Represents the structure of a single entry
    """
    __tablename__ = "reports"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent = Column(Integer)
    time_created = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    time_updated = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), onupdate=func.now())
    signature = Column(Text)
    report_data = Column(JSON)
```

and then in my code I do

```
session = self.db.session_maker()
# create entry for parent
report = Report(
    signature=self.dc.session.user
)
session.add(report)
session.commit()
```

and then I'd like to add more `Reports` where the `parent` field holds the `id` of the parent. But not sure what's the best way to retrieve this `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I ended up doing it. Once you've `commit()` the entry for the parent, you can directly access it's `id` as `report.id`. So Alchemy always holds an up-to-date representation of the session.

```
report = Report(
    part_number=parent.assembly,
    revision=parent.revision,
    serial_number=parent.serial,
    signature=self.data_model.session_user
)

session.add(report)
session.commit()

parent_id = report.id
```

Comment: You don't need to commit to get the id - `session.flush()` will do.  That said, what you are doing would be easier if a [relationship](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/tutorial.html#building-a-relationship) existed between your parent and child tables -  you could do `new_parent.children.append(new_child)` without having to either flush or commit first.

Comment: Do you might have a link that explains that in detail? Sounds interesting. But just in case it's not clear from the question, parent and children are not in different tables

Comment: The [flush docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.flush) don't go into detail, but in this case, flushing after `session.add(report)` will cause the database to assign a value for the report's `id`, and that value is communicated back to sqlalchemy.  So you get the `id` without having to commit (though you must commit in the end, of course).